# How to get least and most thousand values of a numeric string in C#?

Tags: c#

As you can see in the code it use several if conditions to achieve the required result.  I only include part of the code which has the same pattern.
At the moment the IdString value can be in between “0” – “99999”.   Later it can be even bigger. If that happen we have to change the code again.

```
private string GetPrefix(string IdString)
    {
        string returnString = string.Empty;

        if (IdString >= 0 && IdString < 1000)
        {
            returnString = "00000";
        }
        else if (IdString >= 1000 && IdString < 2000)
        {
            returnString = "00001";
        }
        else if (IdString >= 2000 && IdString < 3000)
        {
            returnString = "00002";
        }
```

..........//repeate same pattern
..........

```
        else if (IdString >= 49000 && IdString < 50000)
        {
            returnString = "00049";
        }
```

.........//repeate same pattern
.........

```
        else if (IdString >= 99000 && IdString < 100000)
        {
            returnString = "00099";
        }
        else
        {
            returnString = "00000";
        }
        return returnString;
    }
```

Instead of doing that I want to have a function which can do the same. I tried it in the following way but couldn’t get it to work.
The pseudo code:

```
private string ShortFunction(string IdString)
{
        string returnString = string.Empty;
        if (Information.IsNumeric(IdString))
        {
            int intStrId = Convert.ToInt32(IdString);

            int thousandValueOfIdString = HowToExtractFromIdString();//???
            if (IdString > thousandValueOfIdString && IdString < thousandValueOfIdString + 1000)
            {
                returnString = String.Format("????:", thousandValueOfIdString); //eg. "00050";
            }
        }
        return returnString; 
}
```

Can anyone give me an idea?

**NOTE**:I am updating inherited code from the previous developers. Original code has been modified several times during past 2 years as IdString increased beyond the assumed value. When I traced, I found that this IdString coming from auto incremented bigint column in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What should happen if `IdString` is equal to 1000?

Comment: So basically you want `(int)(IdString/1000)`? Is the padding important too?

Comment: Can you in addition to showing some strange code explain what is expected result for incoming number like ( "for number n return to string padded with 0 on left up to .... characters")

Comment: @GrantWinney. Padding always three 0s on left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to an `int`, perform integer division (which drops the fractional part), and [pad the string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048(v=vs.110).aspx) using the `D` [numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
return (Convert.ToInt32(IdString) / 1000).ToString("D5");
```

Output:

```
1000 -> 00001
```

If the number goes higher than 99999, you can either increase the number 5 in `D5` to add more leading zeroes, or just leave it as is.

> @GrantWinney. Padding always three 0s on left.

In that case, if you want a minimum of three zeroes for padding, I'd split it into two lines of code. I'm using the Math.Max method to provide 5 zeroes on smaller number, but at least 3 zeroes on larger numbers.

```
var thous = (Convert.ToInt32(IdString) / 1000).ToString();

return thous.PadLeft(Math.Max(5, thous.Length + 3), '0');
```

Output:

```
1000   -> 00001
22500  -> 00022
999999 -> 000999
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private String ShortFunction(string IdString)
{
    Int32 id = Int32.Parse(IdString);                           // Convert input to a workable numeric value
    Int32 outputInt = id / 1000;                                // Obtain the thundsand value you after
    String outputString = outputInt.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0'); // Convert the output number to desired string format
    return outputString;
}
```

.

Notes on proposed method:

- You may require to expand for input validation on edge cases (eg/ what happen with IdString contains a negative value)
- I use Int32 which handles up to 2,147,483,647 only.
- The output will exceed 5 character string value if input value contains > 100,000,000.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert `IdString` to `int`, then get rid of the last 3 digits

something like this

```
int number = int.Parse(IdString);
int result = (number - (number%1000))/1000;
```

just `number/1000` works too, but I don't like that practice very much, so I avoid it.

```
if(result >100) 
    return "00000";  //check the last case
```

Then, convert it back to `String`

```
return result.ToString("D5"); //this gives you the number with 5 digits
```